# difficulties with the php part of JOIN of one-to-many relational database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I think I got the MySQL part of my database correct. After tons of studying, I created an InnoDB database with two tables: Venues and Events.

Each venue has a unique ID (VENUE_ID) that I indexed. Then each event has a column by the name of VENUE_LOCATION that has the ID number of the venue the event belongs to.
This is how I have the event table is set up :)

[image]

I think that's all good, now I'm having problems getting all of that data displayed using php :/

So far I've done simple stuff such as select data from a single table but I'm lost as to how I can retrieve the information from the events table, AND insert all of the corresponding information from VENUES depending on what number is in 'VENUE_LOCATION'.

And I really have searched up so many examples and tutorials but I have found nothing that exactly shows what I want to do. Any tips as to which direction I should take are greatly appreciated :)!
Thanks again

Edit:
Here's what I have now

```
<?php

$dbuser="nightl7_main";
$dbpass="mypw";
$dbname="nightl7_complete";  //the name of the database
$chandle = mysql_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass) 
    or die("Connection Failure to Database");
mysql_select_db($dbname, $chandle) or die ($dbname . " Database not found. " . $dbuser);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example")
or die(mysql_error());  
return $result;


?>
```

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the two tables in your `SELECT` statement: http://sqlzoo.net/3b.htm

Comment: BTW: START_TIME and END_TIME are stored as 09AM or 06AM? Be aware of such things, if there is a chance, that you ever have an international audience (like across Europe) or in different time-zones (like across the USA). Better store times and dates in an absolute format, e.g. `1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00`, [W3C notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: You're not catching the error from MySQL, which would provide pertinent details to you about your query...

Comment: Tried this with no luck SELECT * FROM events INNER JOIN venues ON events.VENUE_LOCATION=venues.VENUE_ID Maybe I set up the database keys wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT e.*, v.* FROM Events e
INNER JOIN Venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID
```

This will select all the information of events and all the information of the venue where the event has taken place.

---

#### EDIT

This is the PHP code you could be using for starters:

```
<?php

$dbuser = 'nightl7_main';
$dbpass = 'mypw';
$dbname = 'nightl7_complete';  //the name of the database
$chandle = mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die('Connection Failure to Database');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $chandle) or die ($dbname . ' Database not found. ' . $dbuser);

$query = 'SELECT e.*, v.* FROM Events e '.
         'INNER JOIN Venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['ID'].' '.$row['VENUE_LOCATION'].' '.$row['IMAGE_URL'].'<br />'; // access any column you like here
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Shef :) Can I ask for one more help though? I created this php code from what you helped me with, and the result is an empty page :/
I posted the code in my post above for an easier read. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi OMG Ponies, thanks for your reply :) However, when I search google for 'php ON clause' all I get are results for a WHERE clause :/ Would you mind explaining the error a little deeper please? Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @pufAmuf: I had forgotten the `ON` clause for the query to work (as OMG Ponies mentioned). Edit your question to add the PHP code so we can help with that as well.

Comment: Hi Shef, I already added the php code I had above - did some minor changes to it.

Comment: Thank you Shef! I was actually wondering about this - Do I need to 'echo' everything that I want to show? I was trying to find a code everywhere that would just take all of the columns and print them but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @pufAmuf: Yes, you would have to do that.